# Time series data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am storing time series data for sensors and things in MongoDB , I followed the UPDATE model approach to store data , below is the sample JSON that I have stored

[Schema Design for Time Series Data in MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com//blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb#comment-3112273650)

JSON Model

- Document by Hour (granularly having data for minutes and second)
- phenomenonTime and thingsId will serve as Unique key

Sample

```
[
    {
        "id": "58808b1819f61",
        "phenomenonTime": "2017-01-19T5:00:00",
        "observations": {
            "0": {
                "0": {
                    "location": {
                        "coordinates": [
                            0.0066,
                            0.0009
                        ]
                    },
                    "temperature": 20,
                    "device_id_gateway": "",
                },
                "1": {
                    "location": {
                        "coordinates": [
                            -0.0003,
                            0.0032
                        ]
                    },
                    "temperature": 16,
                    "airSpeed": ""
                }, ............. so on
```

Now for reporting I am trying to get the following information but I am not getting the queries to get the data with this approach

- Where was this sensor at time x("2017-01-19T5:30:15")?
- Track the movement of sensor between time x and y i.e  time interval "2017-01-19T5:30:15" to "2017-01-19T8:24:23"

**Could you please help me to understand how can I get this information**

Some related questions

for now I am getting the data from one gateway for multiple devices but I can have multiple gateways so in that case please suggest what should be the model

- Single Gateway - Multiple Device
- Multiple Gateway - Single Device
- Multiple Gateway - Multiple Device

Comment: When you are updating, old data is deleted. is it ?

Comment: No..it  is not deleted

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you can have documents for each data (data from each device at a time). To answer your questions,

1. Where was this sensor at time x("2017-01-19T5:30:15")?
   You can query by the time.
2. Track the movement of sensor between time x and y i.e time interval "2017-01-19T5:30:15" to "2017-01-19T8:24:23"?
   Mongodb has facility to query time intervals and then you can sort it.
3. The design - 
   forget MYSQL, in mongodb I think the best schema is one document per one data request.(schema is changing per device,gateway) and you can keep ids for gateways and devices and save in relevant documents.

Comment: Did you got a chance to look at https://www.mongodb.com//blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb#comment-3112273650